# getOWLDatatypeMinInclusiveRestriction for decimal bounds

Tags: owl-api

I have two questions :

(1) The function `getOWLDatatypeMinInclusiveRestriction` (and similarily for MaxInclusive, (min, max) exclusive) for constraining facets 
for the datatype accept as input only double or integer values.

Is that means that facets restrictions with OWL API cannot be applied for decimals.

(2) How can I get the datatype of a dataTypeProperty by OWL API?

Answer (score 0):

1) the methods you mention are shorthand for (perceived) most common uses. You can create the same restrictions with decimals but you'll have to create the literals and combine them manually. I don't have an example at hand but can add one later if you need.

2) look for data property range axioms on that property.